# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansPhaseListener.afterPhase when two WAR in one EAR

Tags: jsf, ear, omnifaces

I have two JSF based WAR projects in one EAR archive, both projects have OmniFaces as dependency and they both will be deployed.
when deploy throw this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerBeansPhaseListener.afterPhase(EagerBeansPhaseListener.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

if remove OmniFaces from one war, deploy work fine.

Omnifaces 2.3, PrimeFaces 5.3, Payara 4.1.152

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem which is caused by an unclarity in CDI specification. See also:

- [OmniFaces wiki - Known Issues (CDI)](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/wiki/Known-Issues-(CDI))
- [The BalusC Code - CDI behaved unexpectedly](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/cdi-behaved-unexpectedly-in-ear-so.html)

I must admit that `@Eager` wasn't tested in a multi-module EAR. This `NullPointerException` is unfortunate, it is never the intent to make the web application unusable this way. At most only the OmniFaces CDI-related feature should be unusable, but the rest should continue working.

I have created [issue 290](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/290) on this and I will re-test all CDI functionality in a multi-module EAR against the currently available servers as per [issue 281](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/281).

Your best bet is to edit the OmniFaces JAR and remove the `EagerBeansPhaseListener` from its `/META-INF/faces-config.xml`. Only the [`@Eager`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Eager) functionality for view scoped beans will stop working.

---

**Update** as per [issue 290](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/290) I have fixed this NPE. It's available in today's [2.5-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.5-SNAPSHOT/).

Comment: i use only FullAjaxExceptionHandler. Edit Omnifaces Jar is possible when import with maven?

Comment: If you maintain your own Maven repo, yes. An alternative would be to use 2.5-SNAPSHOT (after I've committed a quickfix on the NPE).